# GridView not refreshing?

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview

I am working on an Android app that has only one activity and several fragments.

One of the fragments contains a GridView with a custom adapter.

The data shown in the GridView are loaded from a remote server database.

On another fragment the user can add items to the remote database, and after sending the data the app opens the fragment that contains the GridView again, but the data are not updated with the last included item.

Here you have the method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("MISUPICKS","ESTOE EN MISUPICKS ONCREATE");

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_misupicks, container, false);

    txtbusqueda = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtbusqueda);

    botonbuscar =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnbuscar);

    botonbuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        String busqueda = txtbusqueda.getText().toString();
        getUpicksBusquedaFromDB(0, busqueda);
      }
    });

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    upicks = new ArrayList<>();

    gridLayout = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayout);

    adapter = new UpicksAdapter(getActivity(), upicks);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    upicks.clear();

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    getUpicksFromDB(0);
    return view;
}
```

You can find there the method getUpicksFromDB(0) which actually loads the data from the remote server:

```
private void getUpicksFromDB(int id) {
    Log.d("MISUPICKS","ESTOE EN MISUPICKS getupicksfromddb");

    AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Integer... addressesIds) {
        //  Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "UID REGISTRADO ANTES DE CARGAR REECYCLER: " + user_id);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://.../upicks_todos.php")
            .build();
        try {
          okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

          JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

          for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.d("HOLA ADDRESSES", "DIRECCION LEIDA: " + i);
            Upicks upicks = new Upicks(object.getInt("id_servicio"),
                object.getString("driver_servicio"),
                object.getString("inicio_servicio"),
                object.getString("lat_origen_servicio"),
                object.getString("lon_origen_servicio"),
                object.getString("lat_destino_servicio"),
                object.getString("lon_destino_servicio"),
                object.getString("cliente_servicio"),
                object.getString("final_servicio"),
                object.getString("distancia_servicio"),
                object.getString("tarifa_servicio"),
                object.getString("origen_servicio"),
                object.getString("destino_servicio"),
                object.getString("estado_servicio"),
                object.getString("tiempo_servicio")
            );

            MisUpicksFragment.this.upicks.add(upicks);
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
    };

    asyncTask.execute(id);
}
```

What should I change to refresh the data every time the fragment is shown?

EDIT:

Adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.juarezserver.upick.R;
import com.juarezserver.upick.fragment.DetalleUpickFragment;

import java.util.List;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;


public class UpicksAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UpicksAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Upicks> upicks;
    private String emailsegundo;

    private SharedPreferences mPref;
    private  static final String PREF_NAME = "directorio";

    public UpicksAdapter(Context context, List<Upicks> upicks) {
        this.context = context;
        this.upicks = upicks;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.upick_card,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

       // holder.txtapodo.setText(upicks.get(position).getid_servicio());
        holder.txtOrigen.setText(upicks.get(position).getorigen_servicio());
        holder.txtDestino.setText(upicks.get(position).getdestino_servicio());
       // holder.txtapellidos.setText(upicks.get(position).getApellidos());
        //holder.txtempresa.setText(upicks.get(position).getEmpresa());
      //  String url_foto = "http://.../usuarios/"+ upicks.get(position).getImagen();
    //    Glide.with(context).load(url_foto).into(holder.imageView);



    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return upicks.size();
    }

    public  class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{



        public TextView txtOrigen;
        public TextView txtDestino;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtOrigen = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtOrigen);
            txtDestino = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDestino);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            showPopupMenu(v,position);
        }
    }

    private void showPopupMenu(View view, int poaition) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_context_upick, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuClickListener(poaition));
        popup.show();
    }


    class MenuClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
        Integer pos;
        public MenuClickListener(int pos) {
            this.pos=pos;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_favourite:




                    mPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);


                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPref.edit();

                    editor.putString("NOMBRE", upicks.get(pos).getinicio_servicio());
          //          editor.putString("APELLIDOS", upicks.get(pos).getApellidos());
          //          editor.putString("APODO", upicks.get(pos).getApodo());
                    //          editor.putString("CUMPLE", upicks.get(pos).getCumple());
//

                    //      editor.putString("CONYUGE", upicks.get(pos).getConyuge());
                    //       editor.putString("CUMPLE_CONYUGE", upicks.get(pos).getCumple_conyuge());
                    //       editor.putString("ANIVERSARIO_BODAS", upicks.get(pos).getAniversario_bodas());
                    //       editor.putString("EMPRESA", upicks.get(pos).getEmpresa());
                    //       editor.putString("DIRECCION_EMPRESA", upicks.get(pos).getDireccion_empresa());

                    //       editor.putString("TEL_NEGOCIO", upicks.get(pos).getTel_negocio());
                    //         editor.putString("FECHA_INGRESO", upicks.get(pos).getFecha_ingreso());
                    //       editor.putString("NUM_ROTARIO", upicks.get(pos).getNum_rotario());
                    //        editor.putString("PADRINO", upicks.get(pos).getPadrino());
                    //       editor.putString("DIRECCION_CASA", upicks.get(pos).getDireccion_casa());

                    //       editor.putString("TEL_CASA", upicks.get(pos).getTel_casa());
                    //      editor.putString("CELULAR", upicks.get(pos).getCelular());
                    //      editor.putString("EMAIL", upicks.get(pos).getEmail());

                    //   Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "RESPONSE 2 valor=" + upicks.get(pos).getEmail_privado());
                    //    emailsegundo = "-";

                    //       if("null".equals(upicks.get(pos).getEmail_privado()))
                    //       {
                    //        emailsegundo = "-";
                    //       Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "RESPONSE 2 no hay " + upicks.get(pos).getEmail_privado());
                    //      }
                    //    else
                    //    {
                    //         emailsegundo = upicks.get(pos).getEmail_privado();
                    //Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "RESPONSE 2 email: " + upicks.get(pos).getEmail_privado());


                    //  }


                    //  editor.putString("EMAIL_PRIVADO", emailsegundo);


                    //      editor.putString("CLASIFICACION", upicks.get(pos).getClasificacion());
                    //    editor.putString("IMAGEN", upicks.get(pos).getImagen());

                    //    Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "RESPONSE rotario  en direcadapter: " + upicks.get(pos).getNum_rotario());



                    //    editor.apply();





                 DetalleUpickFragment firstFragment = new DetalleUpickFragment();
                  ((MainActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                           .add(R.id.frame, firstFragment).commit();

                    return true;

                default:
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the UpicksAdapter implementation? The way the objects are stored internally may be the cause of the issue.

Comment: @punisher_malade, I have include the adapter implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    i think you are going wrong in coding..
you should try like this way:

1 for set adapter-



gridLayout = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayout);
    adapter = new UpicksAdapter(getActivity(), upicks);

2. change data on click:

     botonbuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

      upicks.clear(); // clear your list
                    before adding new data

     String busqueda = txtbusqueda.getText().toString();

     getUpicksBusquedaFromDB(0, busqueda);

       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //for update list

     //-- Note-- Make sure your "adapter" instance will not be create "adapter = new .." again and again.

                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don´t see any change in your proposal

Comment: Yes, i am trying to explain that you have to change your sequence of code as mention above.

Comment: Thank you, but you are changing the sequence at another place, botonbuscar is only launch for terms searching, this is not the main gridview population